# ASP.net: Password Textbox cannot contain name entered

Tags: asp.net

Learning, be kind.  This is for a ASP.net webform.  I have a text box for a user to enter their name and some other items.  There is also a create a password textbox and a textbox for retyping the password.

I need the password box to not validate if it has their name in it at all(name from the textbox for name).  How do I go about this?  I understand how to see if fields match, but not how to deny if they do etc.

Here is a small portion of my code:

```
    <strong>Enter Your Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong><asp:Textbox id="tbName" runat="server" Width="183px"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="tbName"
  ErrorMessage="A name must be entered!"
  ForeColor="red"
 />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
ErrorMessage="Name entered is not valid!" 
ControlToValidate="tbName"     
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$"
ForeColor="red" />
    <strong>Enter Your Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong><asp:Textbox id="tbPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"  Width="188px"  MaximumValue="12" 
  MinimumValue="6" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="tbPass"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="tbPass"
  ForeColor="red"
  ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8}$" 
  ErrorMessage="You must enter a password!">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"     
ControlToValidate="tbPass"     
ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8}$" 
ErrorMessage="Password must contain: 8 characters, one upper, one lower and one Number."
ForeColor="red" />
```